Isoperimetric inequality on the torus?
I am interested how a result for spheres carries over to torus surfaces. On the n-dimensional sphere $S^{n}$, you can take the usual arclength metric $\rho_n$ and define the spherical measure $\sigma^n$ (see the Wikipedia article "Spherical measure"). This allows you to formulate the isoperimetric inequality for spherical measures:
For $A \subset S^{n}$ a Borel set and $B \subset S^{n}$ a $\rho_n$-ball (i.e. $B$ is a "spherical cap") with $\sigma^n(A)=\sigma^n(B)$ , and for any $r > 0$, the following inequality holds
$$ \sigma ^{n}(A_{r})\ \geq\ \sigma ^{n}(B_{r})$$
where $A_r$ denotes the "inflation" or "blowup" of $A$ by $r$, i.e.
$$ A_{r}:=\{x\in S^{n}\mid \rho _{n}(x,A)\leq r\}$$
and similarly for $B_r$. [In the definition of $A$ and $B$, the Wikipedia article uses $S^{n-1}$ but I think this is an error; I think it should be $S^n$]

I am interested whether there is a similar inequality for the 2-torus $T^2$ ? By $T^2$ I mean a 2-dimensional circular torus manifold embedded in ${\bf R}^3$ with no self-intersection and with metric inherited from the ambient space ${\bf R}^3$. (If this torus definition can be easily extended to $T^n$ embedded in ${\bf R}^{n+1}$, then I would love to receive this more general answer. The requirement of no self-intersection is important for me.)


To avoid hard special cases, let me add a simplifying assumption: let us assume that the minimum shape $B$ is small enough; such that $B$ and $B_r$ do not self-intersect for "small" $r$ (i.e. $B$ and $B_r$ stay topologically disc-like).

I have tried to find a reference, but I could only find articles about discrete torii (in the area of combinatorics and graph theory).
I have posted a related question here on Math Stackexchange, but that one is a more technical one related to spherical measures. So, the two questions are of a very different nature and I was advised to post them separately. Here is the link to the other question: Spherical isoperimetric inequality: condition for strict inequality (i.e. "$>$"), and lower bound proof?

Anything in Santalo's book on Integral Geometry and Geometric Probability?

Welcome to MSE! <> To clarify, what is a "torus"? I'm guessing it refers to a flat Riemannian manifold obtained from a Euclidean (unit?) $n$-cube by identifying opposite faces in a conventional way, but it would be good if you could edit the question to confirm or correct this guess.

@Paul Thanks a lot for your suggestion. I have looked up Santalo's book (the part about isoperimetric inequalities) but could not find the answer there.

Thank you for the edit! <> If it matters, the new constraint looks like it makes the question ... Hard: Assuming we're speaking of a circular torus with minor radius $r$ and major radius $R$, the perimeter of a disk of specified radius depends on $r$, $R$, and the center of the disk (a circular torus is not "homogeneous"). Further, a geometric disk is not topologically disk-like if its radius is greater than $\pi r$; instead, the disk "wraps around and overlaps itself." (This type of behavior doesn't occur with spheres.)

Kind of appears you are asking about Bishop-Gromov. http://staff.ustc.edu.cn/~wangzuoq/Courses/24S-RiemGeom/Notes/Lec26.pdf    let me read some more

@AndrewD.Hwang Thank you for your comment, I have added a hopefully simplifying assumption: that the disk A is small enough; such that $A$ and $A_r$ do not self-intersect for "small" $r$ (i.e. $A$ and $A_r$ stay topologically disc-like).
